# Single crystal LiF solid state NMR

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy, reference-request, solid-state-chemistry

I haven't been able to find any literature on $\ce{^{19}F}$ solid state NMR studies of $\ce{LiF}$ crystals, not even $\ce{LiF}$ powders. Is there any NMR chemists who is familiar with $\ce{LiF}?$ Any references are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can get this reference free: !http://esl.ecsdl.org/content/14/9/A134.abstract

Comment: Here is it: !http://esl.ecsdl.org/content/14/9/A134.full.pdf+html

Comment: Another one is here. Hope these are helpful: !https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022459608004751

Comment: There are quite a few refs for this compound e.g.
J. Phys. Chem. C20091133315018-15023
Rob

Comment: This is not a directly responsive answer (mea culpa) but I want to give you any help I can. LiF is a very well known reference standard for X ray powder diffraction. Perhaps parsing this literature would still help you with the problem you are working on. Again mea culpa, not a direct answer...but giving what I can since nothing else has helped so far. Take a look at the powder diffraction literature. May get some comments or insights that help you.